# Django 4 async StreamingHTTPResponse and sending a large generated zipfile

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, streaming

I'm trying to zip some large files in Django and stream them to the client as a zipfile. The problem is that it tends to want to create the zipfile into memory first and then send. This causes the memory to run out and Django crashes. Writing the zipfile to disk prior to sending is also not feasible, due to limited storage space.

I was able to do this using the [zipfly](https://github.com/sandes/zipfly) package and it worked fine when Django was running synchronously in WSGI. But then I needed to implement WebSockets and had to make Django run asynchronously in ASGI, and the streaming zipfly implementation broke.

So I started to write my own implementation and almost got it working but there are issues. It is currently attempting to create the zip on the fly, but it is still using quite a bit of memory. Also my code is not sending an indication to the client that the datastream has ended, causing the browser to abort the transfer in the end.

Can anyone assist me? Here is the code:

```
async def create_zip_streaming_response(files_to_compress: list, filename: str):
# Create a generator function to yield chunks of data
async def generate():
    # Create an in-memory byte buffer to store the compressed data
    buffer = BytesIO()

    # Create a zip file object
    with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
        # Iterate over the files and add them to the zip file
        for file_path in files_to_compress:
            # Get the file name from the file path
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

            # Add the file to the zip file
            zip_file.write(file_path, file_name)

            # Flush the buffer to ensure data is written
            buffer.flush()

            # Move the buffer's read position to the beginning
            buffer.seek(0)

            # Read the data from the buffer
            data = buffer.read()

            # Yield the generated data in chunks
            yield data

            # Reset the buffer for the next file
            buffer.truncate(0)

    # Create a streaming response using the generator function
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate(), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'

    return response
```

I would really appreciate the help. This is for a hobby project that is very dear to me and I don't know how to get over this issue. The project is deployed in docker and uses nginx in production, in conjunction with uvicorn.

Comment: did you ever end up figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Nope, never got it working

Comment: Ah too bad, thanks for the response. I decided to just use aiohttp for my thing instead since django was feeling like serious overkill.

Comment: I got too much going on in that Django, dont want to axe it. But I was thinking about making a separate downloading application using synchronous FastAPI. Maybe that would work and I could have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i got it working by modified your implementation by adding a final "flush" and using an own buffer implementation. During testing i haven't spotted any mentioned problems.

```py
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = bytearray()

    def write(self, data):
        self.buf.extend(data)
        return len(data)
    
    def flush(self):
        pass

    def take(self):
        buf = self.buf
        self.buf = bytearray()
        return bytes(buf)

    def end(self):
        buf = self.buf
        self.buf = None
        return bytes(buf)

def create_zip_streaming_response(*args):
    files_to_compress = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.csv']

    def generate():
        buffer = Buffer()

        # Create a zip file object
        with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
            for file_path in files_to_compress:
                zip_file.writestr(file_path, "This is file " + file_path)

                yield buffer.take()

        yield buffer.end()

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate(), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="test.zip"'
    return response
```

Comment: Works wonderfully. The downside is that it only works in WSGI synchronous Django. Where my ultimate goal has been ASGI asynchronous, so that I can use streaming large zipfiles and websockets in a single application